# Nothing shows up on the map

Tags: pokemon-go

When I load up Pokémon GO, none of the pokéstops, gyms, or pokémon show up on the map.

Is there a fix for this? I am on iOS.

Comment: You didn't try to cheat, did you?

Comment: Sounds like when you try to GPS spoof, you get sent to a blank plane with nothing around you

Comment: I've also seen it happen during moments of network lag, but it usually resolves itself after a moment. It's possible the game could get stuck in this state. Closing and reopening the app should fix it.

Comment: Are you inside a well populated city? There need to be many people and interesting places near your.

Comment: I cannot answer a protected post.. But you can try: settings > general > reset > reset network settings. It worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your [mobile data is on](http://deviceguides.vodafone.ie/web/apple-iphone-6-plus-ios8/change-settings/data-usage/turn-mobile-data-on-or-off), enable [your GPS](http://deviceguides.vodafone.ie/web/apple-iphone-6-plus-ios8/explore/gps-maps-and-navigation/turn-gps-on-or-off), and make sure you [close any other applications](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201330) that could accidentally change your GPS settings.

Then, try closing Pokémon GO and opening it again.

Hope this helps!