# Nearby tracker doesn't refresh

Tags: pokemon-go

This is a related question:

[Nothing shows up on the map](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280099/pokemon-go-need-help)

but it is a little old and had no effective answers, so I hope this acceptable.

My GPS and internet connection (I've tried both on wifi and mobile data) are working fine, also the game works fine, I already have some pokémons, but my problem is that the "Nearby Tracker" doesn't automatically refresh, so getting pokemon is a very 'random' and hard process.

In pratice, I can walk a lot and the pokemons showing up on the list remain unchanged. I then close the game and re-open it to find that the list is completely new, like if it was frozen before.

I've noticed that my friend's phones show up a white-spinning loading pokemon on the top left quite frequently and I believe this signs that the game is connecting with the servers. In my phone, this loading ball shows up one time and then disappears forever.

I should mention that I downloaded an APK before the release in my country, so this could have something to do with it.

**So, how can I make my nearby tracker refresh/load?**

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid we don't help with pirated copies.  Wait until the game is released in your country.

Comment: To be noted, I have noticed this problem as well without a pirated copy. I just assumed it was because the feature is super buggy, so I don't bother even looking at it anymore.

Comment: It was officialy released yesterday in Brazil. I'm just mentioning for technical sake that I have used a pirate version before (I'm using the official now), since it may have caused some trouble. Still, I think it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Then it's a dupe of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280088/cant-click-on-pokemon-in-the-nearby-menu-and-no-footseps-showing-for-distance

Comment: If you read the question, it is clearly not a duplicate of this.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the APK and the legit copy?

Comment: The APK I've deleted a long time ago. I uninstalled the official today and installed again and the issue continues. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the person who asked the question. Just to give it back to the community:

I found a solution for my problem, but it is somewhat hidden within the internet, so I put it here.

I went on to Settings>Date and Time and then marked the box that said something like "update date and time from internet" or similar. It worked and know nearby tracker refreshes perfectly.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

The nearby tracker refreshes every time the game checks in with the servers. Since you played on an illegal APK, Niantic softbanned many users that did that. I've heard of many different forms of softbanning, from never seeing stops, to not being able to catch pokemon. Sounds like your softban is not being able to update the tracker... not that bad considering it doesn't work well for anyone anyway.

Contact Niantic support about the issue and see if you can get it worked out now that the game is out for your region and you are playing it "correctly"

Comment: I haven't been softbanned as far as I can tell (I don't spood etc.), but my tracker doesn't update. Not that I would use it anyways as only knowing something is within 70m from you isn't particularly useful if you have no idea of knowing which way to walk.

Comment: @Dragonrage With the green outline ping you should be able to know which way to walk to find pokemon in your tracker.

Answer (score 0):

The Nearby Tracker is currently broken (as of Aug 4). It wasn't calculating distance to Pokemon properly, so Niantic took it down partially in the last patch. Until they bring it up, Pokemon hunting will require actual hunting instead of assisted stalking. Enjoy! :)

Comment: I'm aware that they removed things such as the little paws which measured distance. However, I believe that this issue I mention has not much to do with that because my friends' tracker is working nicely, automatically updating as they walk.

Comment: "Hunting" and "walk in a random direction for something that may or may not be there" are quite different things.

Comment: @Ellesedil Only if you know how to hunt properly. Otherwise, I've found they are quite similar.